# Multiple Time Series with Binary Outcome Prediction

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

I'll preface this with saying I am extremely new to neural networks and their operation. I've done a fair bit of reading, played with a few cloud based tools (Cortana and AWS), but beyond that, I am not well adept in the algorithms, the kind of neural networks etc...

I'm looking for advice on what systems / tools / kinds of algorithms I can use to achieve the below.

**Problem Description**

I have a data set that contains time series data for a number of users. The data set can contain a variable number of unique users (prob max out at 150), and each user has 4 different sets of time series data for four different variables. Example data set below

V = Variable

User | Time | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4

1 | 12.00am | 13 | 1045 | 12.2 | 52.4

1 | 12.01am | 12 | 1565 | 11.9 | 50.3

2 | 12.00am | 2 | 15434 | 1.93 | 47.2

2 | 12.01am | 2.02 | 17434 | 1.98 | 43.1

And so on for x users and hundreds of data points for each user.

**Required Output**

By parsing the data, I want to be able to train the system to either give back a binary TRUE or FALSE for a user based on the input, or alternatively, a probability % of the user being TRUE.

The binary is effectively a TRUE or FALSE result. There can only be one TRUE of all 10 users. I think getting back a % of chance of being TRUE is probably the simplest form? I may be wrong.

**Input Format**

End point is to have an API that I can send the data set to and it returns user and their probability (or the binary TRUE | FALSE result).

**Systems**

I would prefer to be able to do this on a 3rd party service as opposed to having to build my own systems to do the processing, but not a necessity.

**Training Data**

I have years of data to be able to train the system, hundreds of thousands of real user sets and so on.

**To Wrap It Up**

Looking for advice on the what and the how to predict a binary outcome from multiple time series data sets.

Really appreciate any assistance and guidance here.

Thanks

Russ

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar problem (I am no expert either) but I'll share my approach in case it answers your "what" part of the question.

My solution was to transform the dataset so I ended up with a problem that could be solved with traditional classification algorithms (Random Forest, boosting, ...)

This approach requires that the data is labeled. Each row of the transformed dataset will represent the information associated to each TRUE or FALSE outcome in the training dataset. Each row will be an unique event and will have:

- 1 column with the response
- p sets of columns (one set for each of the p original variables)
- k variables to indicate seasonality

Each set of the p sets of columns will consist of the variable at time t (time when you recorded the response of that row), the variable at time t-1 (lag1), ..., and the variable at time t-T (lagT).

*Example:*

**Original dataset** (I've retained only V1 and V2 and added an outcome variable)

| User | Time | V1 | V2 | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.00am | 13 | 1045 | FALSE |
| 1 | 12.01am | 12 | 1565 | TRUE |

**Transformed dataset**

| ID | V1_lag1 | V1_lag0 | V2_lag1 | V2_lag0 | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| event_id | 13 | 12 | 1045 | 1565 | TRUE |

With this set up you could fit a model that would predict the probability of TRUE at time t for a new observation, based on V1 and V2 evaluated at time t and V1 and V2 evaluated at lag1 (t-1min).

You could also create new features that would describe the variables better (See [Features for time series classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50807/features-for-time-series-classification)).

And you should incorporate the seasonality somehow if the variables show a seasonality pattern:

| ID | V1_lag1 | V1_lag0 | V2_lag1 | V2_lag0 | day | hour | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| event_id | 13 | 12 | 1045 | 1565 | wed | 12am | TRUE |